# React Native Random Crash with UI Hierarchy (UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Hi i'm stuck on my react native development. on Xcode i'm getting the error below.  Unfortunately, its a random crash and it also dosen't really tell me where (especially which view) the error is.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be 
associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <RCTView: 
0x7f91cdeab480; reactTag: 259; frame = (0 0; 414 896); layer = 
<CALayer: 0x600001a2af20>> is associated with <UIViewController: 
0x7f91d01ca240>. Clear this association before associating this view 
with <UIViewController: 0x7f91cdc998b0>.'
```

Because i'm using react native, most of the native code is unknown to me. I know i can view UI hierarchy on xcode but it dosen't work after the app crashes ("JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)

After the app crashes my screen just looks like this. Does anyone know where / how i can start to try to debug this further?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh from the screenshot i can quite clearly see its from react-native-view-pager

Problem is documented here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/issues/167

And fixed in 4.1